# SQL Query to find pairs of EMPLOYEES who have the same DEPTNO

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a query finding the pairs of `ENAME`'s with the same `DEPTNO`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.ENAME as W1, m.ENAME AS W2
FROM EMP e 
INNER JOIN emp m ON e.DEPTNO = m.DEPTNO AND e.ENAME != m.ENAME --AND m.ENAME != e.ENAME
ORDER BY e.ENAME;
```

the pairs should not be the same...
how to get rid of pairs like (to present only one of them):

```
BLAKE <==> WORD
WORD  <==> BLAKE
```

Comment: Use `<` rather than `!=`.

Comment: Use `e.ename > m.ename` assuming that the `ename` values are unique.  If they are not unique but there is an `empno` column that is unique `and e.empno != m.empno and e.ename > m.ename`.  Of course, using `m` as the alias for the `emp` table when you're not using it to get the manager is going to be a bit confusing.

Comment: OK, will change  e to e1 and m to e2... need to analyse ">" later

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the `!=` operator, you can arbitrarily decide to put the first name (lexicographically) always on the left (or, alternatively, on the right, of course. But let's go with left, for argument's sake):

```
SELECT     DISTINCT e.ENAME as W1, m.ENAME AS W2
FROM       EMP e 
INNER JOIN emp m ON e.DEPTNO = m.DEPTNO AND e.ENAME < m.ENAME
ORDER BY   e.ENAME;
```